# How to fix mypy signature when subclass redefines attribute using @property

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

In my program I have classes similar to the following:

```py
class Dinosaur:
    def __init__(self, roar: str):
        self.roar = roar


class TRex(Dinosaur):
    @property
    def roar(self) -> str:
        return "Roaar!"
```

Mypy returns the following error:

```
error: Signature of "roar" incompatible with supertype "Dinosaur"
```

I need to keep `roar` as an attribute in `Dinosaur` and keep it as a
property-annotated function in `TRex`.

Can I fix this without resorting to letting mypy ignore the line?
Is this a bug in mypy where it does not take into account property-annotated
functions?